# Recgnize if object in SceneKit got clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I want to make a game using scenekit for ios. I started with the SceneKit template Xcode gives us (a rotating Airplane). There already the handleTap method provided for recognizing if the user tapped on the screen. I want to make a SCNBox and recognize if the user taps on it, but I am confused how handleTap works. 
Do I have to add the box geometry in handleTap? 
Can someone please show me how you would have a box placed in the center of the screen being able to recognize if it got clicked.

Here is handleTap code:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognize{
  // retrieve the SCNView
  SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;

  // check what nodes are tapped
  CGPoint p = [gestureRecognize locationInView:scnView];
  NSArray *hitResults = [scnView hitTest:p options:nil];

  // check that we clicked on at least one object
  if([hitResults count] > 0){
      // retrieved the first clicked object
      SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];

      // get its material
      SCNMaterial *material = result.node.geometry.firstMaterial;

      // highlight it
      //[SCNTransaction begin];
      //[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];

      // on completion - unhighlight
      [SCNTransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
          [SCNTransaction begin];
          [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];

          material.emission.contents = [UIColor blackColor];

          [SCNTransaction commit];
      }];

      material.emission.contents = [UIColor redColor];

  [SCNTransaction commit];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the template only looks for the material:

```
SCNMaterial *material = result.node.geometry.firstMaterial;
```

you'll want to check against the result's node:

```
if (result.node == _boxNode) { ... }
```

Comment: What is result.node?

Comment: well, in the template you have `SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];` and `node` is just a property on `SCNHitTestResult `

Comment: So do I need to call a new handle method, or can I just implement the if statement inside the method